# How to draw multiple rectangles with different colors in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, charts

```js
        Chart.pluginService.register({
            beforeDraw: function (chart, easing) {
                
                    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
                    var chartArea = chart.chartArea;
                    const scales = chart.scales["x-axis-0"]
                    const leftMargin = scales.left;
                    const width = scales.width / 7;
                
                    ctx.save();

                //as below, I can draw multiple rects
                    ctx.fillRect(leftMargin, chartArea.top, width, chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top);
                    ctx.fillRect(leftMargin + width * 2, chartArea.top, width, chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top);

                //but I can't handle them seperately 
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(10, 10, 10);
                    ctx.restore();
                
            }
        });
```

The code above shows what is my problem, and my question is that how to handle them seperately? I'm just a beginner in chart.js, and I don't completely understand it's methodologies and working. Maybe I need to create a new context, or add ids to the above codes?

Comment: Did you try to call fillStyle with desired colors before each fillRect?

Comment: Whoa I didn't thought that it will be this simple :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `fillStyle` with the desired colors before each `fillRect`

```js
        Chart.pluginService.register({
            beforeDraw: function (chart, easing) {
                
                    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
                    var chartArea = chart.chartArea;
                    const scales = chart.scales["x-axis-0"]
                    const leftMargin = scales.left;
                    const width = scales.width / 7;
                
                    ctx.save();

                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(10, 10, 10)"; // <--- do this before fillRect
                    ctx.fillRect(leftMargin, chartArea.top, width, chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(20, 20, 20)"; // <--- do this before fillRect
                    ctx.fillRect(leftMargin + width * 2, chartArea.top, width, chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top);

                    ctx.restore();
                
            }
        });
```